# How to identify users and group from UserInformation list in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

I am fetching users from User information list and showing on the page, however, it fetches all the users and some all the group. I can I filter it for users only not for the group?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Ramesh, what are you trying to accomplish, and how are you fetching the users?

Comment: I am working for staff directory in which i need to list the all users.I have made the rest api call to user information list to fetch the all users however it aslo return me the list of groups in it that I would like to filter.

Answer (score 3):

From my testing it seems you can filter on the ContentTypeId which corresponds to the "Person" content type. Groups are listed under the "SharePointGroup" content type. Use the below to pull only users from the User Information List:

```
?$filter=ContentTypeId eq '0x010A0064371926825B4B4D959C7FEE68507C0C'
```

Hope this helps!